# Wordpress - writing data to SQL Server

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, woocommerce

I have a wordpress install hosted on microsoft azure server in a mySQL database.
I have a need to save customer details from the wooComerece shopping cart to a SQL Server also running in Azure.

I have hooked into the details from the wooComerece plugin and I now need to save these details to my SQL Server.

Is this possible? How do I approach it?

Comment: Why do you want to save it to another server? What's wrong with the mysql one?

Comment: want to save our customer details to our application db to save them re-entering all their details again after receiving our product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside your MySQL Database Connection, that stores all relevant Wordpress data, you need a special connection to your MSSQL Database.

You need to setup your PHP Enviroment and make sure that php_mssql extension is installed and activated.

I am not sure, if there is a Wordpress MSSQL PDO Database wrapper you can use for your needs, but one way is to make the queries by yourself:

- Get details from wooComerce
- Open MSSQL Database Connection: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php
- Save Data: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mssql-query.php
- Close MSSQL Database Connection: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-close.php